# Having trouble with implementing tkinter Frame in Class (OOP) [AttributeError: type object 'Frame' has no attribute 'tk']

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to code a minesweeper game in Python. I've created a class called Cell, which is essentially a tkinter Frame object and a Button object placed in the Frame (so that the button shape would be square).

I'm having issues with coding the initializer for this class. So far, I tried

```
def __init__(self, i, j):
    self.n = i*w+j
    Frame(root, height=50, width=50)
    Frame.grid(row=i, column=j)
    Frame.grid_propagate(0)  
    Frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 
    Frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  
    Button(Frame, width=50, height=50, command=self.find_numbers())
```

where find_numbers is defined later. Then I create C0, an instance of Cell. However, I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ssbol/Documents/Python Scripts/Minesweeper.py", line 56, in <module>
    C0 = Cell(0,0)
  File "C:/Users/ssbol/Documents/Python Scripts/Minesweeper.py", line 40, in __init__
    Frame.grid(row=i, column=j)
TypeError: grid_configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I wasn't sure how to fix it, so I just tried messing around and changed Frame to self.frame

```
def __init__(self, i, j):
    self.n = i*w+j
    self.frame = Frame(root, height=50, width=50)
    self.frame.grid(row=i, column=j)
    self.frame.grid_propagate(0)  
    self.frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 
    self.frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  
    self.button = Button(Frame, width=50, height=50, command=self.find_numbers())
```

This time, I received this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ssbol/Documents/Python Scripts/Minesweeper.py", line 56, in <module>
    C0 = Cell(0,0)
  File "C:/Users/ssbol/Documents/Python Scripts/Minesweeper.py", line 44, in __init__
    self.button = Button(Frame, width=50, height=50, command=self.find_numbers())
  File "C:\Users\ssbol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2369, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\ssbol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2292, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Users\ssbol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2262, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: type object 'Frame' has no attribute 'tk'
```

I think I'm in over my head and don't really understand what these error messages entail. Can someone explain what these mean and/or offer a solution? Thank you!

Comment: `self.button = Button(Frame,...)`. You are passing the class `Frame` as the parent widget of `self.button` when you should have passed an instance. Change it to `self.button = Button(self.frame, ...)` to continue with your next problem, which is the command :)

Answer (score 0):

You must call the `__init__` function of the superclass.

```
class MyFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        <your code here>
```